# Imprimir array na tela como texto

Tags: array, java-processing

Como faço para imprimir o conteúdo de um array na tela usando text() na linguagem processing? 
Eu tenho o array peças:

```
final int MAX_SIZE=56;

char[] pecas= new char[MAX_SIZE];
```

Eu adicionei 6 no array. O resto está vazio.

Quando uso um loop e tento usar text dá erro.

Comment: Coloque também o erro que dá na pergunta

Comment: O meu código imprime um quadrado, ao inves dos caracteres que estão no array. E esse o erro.

Comment: os quadrados são memórias não inicializadas